# BackGroundColor DateField

Tags: apache-flex

I'm making a form and I add a DateField, and I would like to change the background font of the textField where the date selected is written but I don't know what I should change, I try with backgroundColor, Color, ColorFont and I just get to change the color of the text.

Thanks in advance,

Alicia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, I try what you say but it does not work. Finally I get it using the style "contentBackgroundColor".

Answer (score 1):

Use textInputStyleName (it's a style inherited from ComboBase) like this:

```
<mx:Style>
    .textInput 
    {
        backgroundColor: #00ff00;
    }
</mx:Style>

<mx:DateField textInputStyleName="textInput"  />
```

If you need to set the style for the DateChooser that gets opened by the DateField, you can do this via dateChooserStyleName in a similar way.

Also, bookmark http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#